# Ruby on rails: Button_to Check post result and update current page

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, button-to

In my UI, I have a table of items. Each row has a favorite button. I am using button to make a rails call to add the db association.

I've been looking into how to check the result of the post response in my button to call.

If it succeeds, I want to disable the favorite button on my page and if it doesn't I want to nothing. Is there a way to check the post response in my button to call and is there a way to stay on the page?

Heres a sample of what I have

```
<%= button_to create_favorite_path(res.id), class: "favorite-btn-#{res.id} btn btn-default" do%>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stay on the page when you click the button, you need to add `remote: true` to your button call. This will make your button request an AJAX call by default.

[Read more about the `button_to` helper here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

```
<%= button_to create_favorite_path(res.id), remote: true, class: "favorite-btn-#{res.id} btn btn-default" do%>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
<% end %>
```

Then to see the response of this AJAX request, you'll need to write some javascript.

In your `application.js` or whatever javascript file you have on this page:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', 'form', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  // do something with data or status
});
```

[Read more about working with javascript in Rails here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Comment: Thank you! So to respond in post, I add respond with right?

Comment: You need to respond to the button press in your `favorites_controller`